# Azure Linux out of band managment

Tags: azure

I have a Linux (Ubuntu) virtual machine running on Azure.
It seems like the only way to connect to it is via SSH.
This is OK for normal operation, but what to do when something goes wrong (`fsck` waiting for user-input, new kernel doesn't boot, mis-configured network, etc.)?

There is a grayed out "Connect" button in the management interface, and the help for it says:

> To access a virtual machine running Windows Server, click Connect and follow the instructions. Enter the password that was set when the virtual machine was created. The Connect button is not available for a virtual machine running Linux, but you can use your favorite SSH program to access it.

I've read the documentation on the [command line tools](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/how-to-guides/command-line-tools/), but there is also no way to connect to it.

Is there any way for me to get such a console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no out of band management console for Linux VMs.

From their support team:

> With these VMs in Azure we do not provide any type of console access. If there is a problem that requires that access, let us know and we can take remedial steps to address the VM.